# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, out-of-memory

I am trying to compare values of lat long provided by user with values of lat long from database. If they are in 15 km radius of each other textview should be changed.
But i am facing following error,

My database contains value source lat = 19.218418 source long = 73.08661
Des lat = 18.9766017 des long = 72.8326658. and values provided by user are 
soure lat = 19.2213935 source long= 73.081532 des lat = 18.9632933 des long = 72.8324848.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.hitesh.nearby, PID: 2156
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5347)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6267)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24763)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5342)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6267) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24763) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
               Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

**Result.java**

```
public class result extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_result);
    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
    String url1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username1");
    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);


    String[] separated = url.split("_");
    String srclat = separated[0];
        Double dsrclat= Double.parseDouble(srclat);
    String srclng = separated[1];
        Double dsrclng= Double.parseDouble(srclng);

    String[] separated1 = url.split("_");
    String deslat = separated1[0];
         Double ddeslat= Double.parseDouble(deslat);
    String deslng = separated1[1];
         Double ddeslng= Double.parseDouble(deslng);

    tv.setText(url);
    tv1.setText(url1);

}

public void Database(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(result.this, feeder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void NearestValue(View view){


    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String s1 = tv.getText().toString();
    String[] separated = s1.split("_");
    String deslat = separated[0];
    Double Lat= Double.parseDouble(deslat);
    String deslng = separated[1];
    Double Lng= Double.parseDouble(deslng);
    ArrayList<String> ssList = new ArrayList<>();
    ssList = myDb.countDatabase(Lat,Lng);
    int ssize = ssList.size();
    TextView tvvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++) {
        tvvv.setText(ssList.get(i));
    }

    TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    String s11 = tv1.getText().toString();
    String[] separated1 = s11.split("_");
    String deslat1 = separated1[0];
    Double Lat1= Double.parseDouble(deslat1);
    String deslng1 = separated1[1];
    Double Lng1= Double.parseDouble(deslng1);
    ArrayList<String> ddList = new ArrayList<>();
    ddList = myDb.countDatabase1(Lat1,Lng1);
    int dsize = ddList.size();
    TextView tvvvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    for(int i=0;i<dsize;i++) {
        tvvv.setText(ddList.get(i));
    }

        for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++){
            String source = ssList.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<dsize;j++) {
                String destination = ddList.get(j);
                String src = myDb.findBus(source, destination);

                    TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    tvv.setText(src);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Nearby.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "halt_details";
    public static final String COL_2 = "snme";
    public static final String COL_3 = "slati";
    public static final String COL_4 = "slong";
    public static final String COL_5 = "dnme";
    public static final String COL_6 = "dlati";
    public static final String COL_7 = "dlong";
    public static final String COL_8 = "buses";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, snme VARCHAR, slati DOUBLE, slong DOUBLE, dnme VARCHAR, dlati DOUBLE, dlong DOUBLE, buses VARCHAR)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertData(String sname, Double slat, Double slng, String dname, Double dlat, Double dlng, String bus) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("snme",sname);
        contentValues.put("slati",slat);
        contentValues.put("slong",slng);
        contentValues.put("dnme",dname);
        contentValues.put("dlati",dlat);
        contentValues.put("dlong",dlng);
        contentValues.put("buses",bus);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    }

    public void clearDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> countDatabase(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
        String sourcename=null;
        double earthRadius = 6371.75;
        ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_3 + " BETWEEN (" +LAT+"- 0.1) AND ("+LAT+" + 0.1) AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " BETWEEN (" +LNG+"- 0.1) AND ("+LNG+" + 0.1)", null);
        mCount.moveToNext();
        while (mCount.moveToFirst()) {
            double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
            double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(Latitude-LAT);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(Longitude-LNG);
            double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
            double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
            double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(LAT)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Latitude));
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            double dist = earthRadius * c;
            if (dist<15){
                sourcename=mCount.getString(1);
                sList.add(sourcename);
            }
        }
        mCount.close();
       return sList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> countDatabase1(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
        String destinationname=null;
        ArrayList<String> dList = new ArrayList<>();
        double earthRadius = 6371.75;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_3 + " BETWEEN (" +LAT+"- 0.1) AND ("+LAT+" + 0.1) AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " BETWEEN (" +LNG+"- 0.1) AND ("+LNG+" + 0.1)", null);
        mCount.moveToFirst();
        while (mCount.moveToNext() ) {
            double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
            double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(Latitude-LAT);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(Longitude-LNG);
            double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
            double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
            double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(LAT)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Latitude));
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            double dist = earthRadius * c;
            if (dist<15){
                destinationname = mCount.getString(4);
                dList.add(destinationname);
            }
        }
        mCount.close();
        return dList;
    }

    public String findBus(String sourcename, String desname){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from search_table where name='" + sourcename + "' AND dname='"+desname+"'", null);
        mCount.moveToFirst();
        String src= mCount.getString(1);
        mCount.close();
         return src;
    }


    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line ,You are getting this exception

Comment: @JyotiJK It makes no difference with an `OutOfMemoryError`.  If a program uses too much memory, the error can happen on any line.

Comment: You need to examine memory use for the entire application using heap dumps and other tools.  Where you exactly get an OOM is semi-random.  But the problem is total memory used by the app.

Comment: can you please elaborate in the answer

Comment: You might also want to debug to see how many rows your queries are actually selecting.  If your query is wrong, or if your database is too big, you could end up getting far more rows than you should, and trying to keep them all in memory.

Comment: my database only has 4 records and my query works fine when executed on Mysql database

Comment: You have database query inside a nested for loop. I'm inclined to think this could be reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you have a few issues within the `findBus` method and the loops that invoke it.

#### 1. Unecessary Loops

The 3 loops around the invocation of the `findBus` method appear to be useless as they repeatedly set the `TextView` but only the last will likely be visible and thus usable. You could go directly to the last element of the `ArrayList`'s by using their `size` method.

I'd suggest that the following :-

```
tvvv.setText(ddList.get(ddList.size()-1));
TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
tvv.setText(myDB.findBus(ssList.get(ssList.size()-1),ddList.get(ddList.size()-1)));
```

should replace :-

```
for(int i=0;i<dsize;i++) {
    tvvv.setText(ddList.get(i));
}

    for(int i=0;i<ssize;i++){
        String source = ssList.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<dsize;j++) {
            String destination = ddList.get(j);
            String src = myDb.findBus(source, destination);

                TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                tvv.setText(src);

        }

    }

}
```

#### 2. Invalid Offset

Additionally within the findBus method you are attempting to access the 2nd column returned from the query, when the query returns only 1 column. i.e. you have coded offset **1** whilst only offset **0** (column **count(*)**) is the only available column.

I'd suggest changing the `findBus` method to :-

```
public String findBus(String sourcename, String desname){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from search_table where name='" + sourcename + "' AND dname='"+desname+"'", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    String src= mCount.getString(0); //<<<< Changed offset to 0 from 1
    mCount.close();
    return src;
}
```

This would likely reduce the memory requirements, if by enough I have no idea though. However, you may also wish to check the **Related** links display to the right in regards to OOM (Out of Memory errors, perhaps the one with **(Andorid)**).

Comment: still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems to be looping issue.

you are not moving to next while using loop for cursor. You have used moveToNext first and in while condition used moveToFirst

update your code as below

```
public ArrayList<String> countDatabase(Double LAT, Double LNG) {
        String sourcename=null;
        double earthRadius = 6371.75;
        ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_3 + " BETWEEN (" +LAT+"- 0.1) AND ("+LAT+" + 0.1) AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " BETWEEN (" +LNG+"- 0.1) AND ("+LNG+" + 0.1)", null);
        mCount.moveToFirst();
        while (mCount.moveToNext()) {
            double Latitude = mCount.getDouble(2);
            double Longitude = mCount.getDouble(3);
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(Latitude-LAT);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(Longitude-LNG);
            double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
            double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
            double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(LAT)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Latitude));
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            double dist = earthRadius * c;
            if (dist<15){
                sourcename=mCount.getString(1);
                sList.add(sourcename);
            }
        }
        mCount.close();
       return sList;
    }
```

Alsoyou are creating Database object but not closing it once it is used.

You need to make sure you are closing cursor as well as database object.
Also I see that you are returning cursor from your method. It will be good if you get data you wanted from cursor, close the cursor and return the data you wanted.

```
public String findBus(String sourcename, String desname){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from search_table where name='" + sourcename + "' AND dname='"+desname+"'", null);
        mCount.moveToFirst();
        String src= mCount.getString(1);
        mCount.close();
        db.close();
         return src;
    }


    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        //Should return the data and close cursor            
        return res;
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.