# How to handle "Map add polyline trying to throw OutOfMemoryError" googlemap polyline draw

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

Android maps - draw polyLine while moving the user. When data points reached 15 thousand points, the app will be crashed due to "OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError"

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

 Process: com.bosch.baronav, PID: 26384
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
2019-05-13 15:23:46.953 26384-26424/com.bosch.baronav E/Crash: Crashed@!#
2019-05-13 15:23:50.606 26384-26542/com.bosch.baronav E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 88 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM, max allowed footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912
        at android.location.Location$2.createFromParcel(Location.java:1083)
        at android.location.Location$2.createFromParcel(Location.java:1079)
        at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:54)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
2019-05-13 15:23:50.607 26384-26542/com.bosch.baronav E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:26384_6
    Process: com.bosch.baronav, PID: 26384
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 88 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM, max allowed footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912
        at android.location.Location$2.createFromParcel(Location.java:1083)
        at android.location.Location$2.createFromParcel(Location.java:1079)
        at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:54)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: Post the code area where you get this exception. And check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461331/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-outofmemoryerror-thrown-while-trying-to-throw-outofm) similar question which might help fix your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461331/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-outofmemoryerror-thrown-while-trying-to-throw-outofm)